# How to make a sliding pane?

Tags: jquery, dojo, openlayers

I would like to modify my OpenLayers based mapping application to include a "sliding" or collapsing side pane similar to the one found here: http://www.chamaps.com/watervliet/, which shows the list of layers.  To the right of the list of layers there is a small triangle you can pick and the layer list will hide/slide/collapse the left.

How can I accomplish this using jQuery or Dojo?

Thanks!

Comment: What about trying to customize a [Jquery-ui accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default) ? You can do that want you want with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this - http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm

I've used it in a few projects now.